# Java reflection and interface as parameter

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I'm trying to invoke a method via reflection. The method in question, let's say

```
public void someMethod(someInterface<someObject> arg1)
```

I do not have access to `someMethod` and `someInterface` at runtime, and have to invoke by

```
someclass.getMethod("someMethod", new Class[]{Class.forName("someInterface")})
         .invoke(...)
```

But it fails with a ClassNotFound exception for `someInterface`. How do I get the `Class` object for interfaces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635025/classnotfound-exception-using-java-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you forgot the interface's package. You have to use fully qualified class name when you are calling Class.forName(), i.e. Class.forName('com.mycompany.MyClass')

Comment: You are so right. I was pulling my hairs out trying to figure out how to get Class for interface, while I just forgot that I need a fully qualified name!

Answer (score 2):

That looks correct to me, conceptually. Check these things:

- Is the interface on the classpath at run time?
- Is the interface public (not package private)
- Is the interface really in the default package (you have to fully qualify it)

Last but not least ;-)

- Check your spelling (case-sensitive)