# How to programmatically read a Java interface?

Tags: java, reflection, interface, field

I'd like to implement a method that returns the field(s) from an interface that define a specified (int) value.  I don't have source to the interface.

So, the signature could be something like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getFieldnames(Object src, int targetValue);
```

And I'm assuming internally it could find the declared fields and test each against the value, returning the list.

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

if( src!= null )
{
    Field[] flist = src.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : flist )
        if( f.getType() == int.class )
            try {
                if( f.getInt(null) == targetValue) {
                    s.add(f.getName());
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            }
}
return s;
```

Unfortunately, this implementation is incorrect - it's as if there are no fields at all when called with the interface itself.  If I pass an object that implements the interface, the list of possible fields will be too wide to be of use.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See below for full answer.  Use `Class<?> src` in signature and change calling site to pass in `MyInterface.class`.  This avoids the internal `getClass()` and works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<String> getFieldnames(Object src, int targetValue) {
  final Class<?> myInterfaceClass = MyInterface.class;
  ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
  if (src != null) {
    for (Class<?> currentClass = src.getClass(); currentClass != null; currentClass = currentClass.getSuperclass()) {
      Class<?> [] interfaces = currentClass.getInterfaces();
      if (Arrays.asList(interfaces).contains(myInterfaceClass)) {
        for (Field field : currentClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
          if (field.getType().equals(int.class)) {
            try {
              int value = field.getInt(null);
              if (value == targetValue) {
                fieldNames.add(field.getName());
              }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
              // Do nothing. Always comment empty blocks.
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return fieldNames;
}
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer since it's the closest other than my own and it reminded me of the `Class<?>` typespec!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
src.getClass()
```

returns src class not interface. Consider this

```
interface I {
}

class A implements I {
}

new A().getClass() -- returns A.class
```

Comment: Exactly!  I'm trying to figure out how to pass in the interface so I can parse it.  I cannot call `getFieldNames(I, aField)`, I cannot call `getFieldNames( new I(){}, aField )` (although that last one compiles) - how do I pass in the interface object to the method?

Comment: You can get all interfaces from the object class -> src.getClass().getInterfaces(), or simply pass it as MyInterface.class

Answer (score 0):

Although I would rather have passed in an object, I suppose changing the signature to a string value and passing in the FQIN gets the job done just as well.

Thanks to <[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516609/java-reflection-and-interface-as-parameter)> for the idea (and Google for directing me there).

Solution:

```
public ArrayList<String> getFieldnamesByValue(Class<?>x, int targetValue)
{
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

    if( x != null )
    {
        Field[] flist = x.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : flist )
            if( f.getType() == int.class )
                try {
                    if( f.getInt(null) == targetValue) {
                        s.add(f.getName());
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use the fully qualified name. Just remove `String interfaceFQName` from the signature, remove that first `try/catch`, and replace it with `Class<?> x = MyInterface.class;`

Comment: That's the key, Alvin.  I changed the signature of the method to `getFieldnames(Class<?>src, int targetValue)` so the body can just get straight into the loop.  At the calling site, I can just quickly nail in `ArrayList<String> names = getFieldNames(SOBConstants.class, 45)` and voila!